# Python and gpio raspberry

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

I have a problem with my project, I have a little python script to read my gas meter.
Every revolution of digits a small magnet inside the gas meter close to the reed switch makes an input for my raspberry. The problem is when the magnet stops close to the sensor circuit leaving on a high level, which cause false inputs, here my script.
Any suggestion? thanks to all

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import datetime
import os.path
import pycurl
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(10, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_DOWN)

GPIO.add_event_detect(10, GPIO.RISING, bouncetime = 5000)

def GetGas(arg):
    time.sleep(0.01)         # need to filter out the false positive of some power fluctuation
    if GPIO.input(10) != GPIO.HIGH:
        return

    gastotale=0
    if os.path.isfile('/var/www/myscripts/gas/gastotale.txt'):
        file = open("/var/www/myscripts/gas/gastotale.txt","r")
        gastotale = float(file.read())
        file.close()
    gastotale = gastotale+0.01

    file = open("/var/www/myscripts/gas/gastotale.txt","w")
    file.write(str(gastotale))
    file.close()

    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    fileday = '/var/www/myscripts/gas/'+now.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")+'.txt'
    gasday = 0

    if os.path.isfile(fileday):
        file = open(fileday,"r")
        gasday = float(file.read())
        file.close()
    gasday = gasday+0.01

    file = open(fileday,"w")
    file.write(str(gasday))
    file.close()

    oem = pycurl.Curl()
    oem.setopt(oem.URL, 'http://emoncms.org/input/post.json?node=0
    csv=0,'+str(gasday)+',0,0,'+str(gastotale)+'&apikey=dfb6ccf')
    oem.perform()

laststate = 0
while True:
    if (GPIO.input(10) == 1 ):
        if (laststate == 0):
            gastotale = gastotale+0.01
            laststate=1
    else:
       laststate=0
    time.sleep(30)
```

Comment: Is there some way to tell apart "true" and "false" inputs - maybe from their timings? If there is, you should elaborate. If there's not, I don't think there's a way to do this on the python side. Have you tried different values for `bouncetime`?

Comment: Aren't you really interested in the falling edge event.  Couldn't you just look for that transition, that way you never have to worry about the magnet being parked next to the reed switch.

Comment: hello! @goncalopp i have tried with bouncetime but i have not solved...

Comment: @Tim Hoffmann, do you have any idea how I could do? thanks

Comment: From the docs http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/  you could use GPIO.FALLING for your event instead of RISING.

Comment: Also you should be using events rather than polling which is what you are actually doing in your code.

Comment: Your GPIO.add_event is not currently doing anything, as you are not using interrupts but polling the state.

Comment: A good example using interrupts is here http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio-part-3

Comment: Hi Tim, thank u very much for your explanation, i have modified my script using the event detect. Could be so Right?